# Configure multiple entry points that created multiple files in angular.json

Tags: angular, webpack

I have earlier worked on angular 5 with webpack where webpack supports multiple entry points that created multiple files

```
  entry: {
    app: 'src/app.ts',
    vendor: 'src/vendor.ts'
  }
```

Link to refer: https://v5.angular.io/guide/webpack

However now I started working on angular 7 which has CLI. I dont find a way this can be handled in angular cli. What is the better of way splitting files into chunks? Should we go ahead and use webpack instead of cli or can it be done using CLI? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm trying to solve the same issue now. I would like to use the `angular.json` serve and build steps to compile my migrations. Did you find a solution?

Comment: @OriolMiró Refer this https://github.com/ParallelTask/ng-starter I have created this repo. Closely refer angular.json and package.json scripts section you will get an idea on how to do it

Comment: It wasn't exactly what I was looking for, because I'm working with Nx, but it helped me to find the way.

Answer (score 0):

Angular CLI is a nice wrapper around some default Webpack settings (among other things). And by default, `ng build` will create the following JS files:

- main.js
- polyfills.js
- runtime.js
- styles.js
- vendor.js

(These files may be suffixed with a hash if you configured it with `"outputHashing": "all"`, which is the default for production)

Also, if you take advantage of lazy-loading for your features modules. Angular CLI may split the app.js into chunks named like 1.chunk.js, 2.chunk.js, etc.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to create chunks of each node modules in vendor js you can do simply configure in webpack.config.js as below:

```
module.exports = {
  //...
  optimization: {
    splitChunks: {
      cacheGroups: {
        commons: {
          test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
          name: 'vendors',
          chunks: 'all'
        }
      }
    }
  }
};
```